# Styled Component v5.3 createGlobalStyles not Working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to create Global Styles for my application using createGlobalStyles but somehow the components are not rendering and I am getting a console warning.

**App.js**

```
import GlobalStyles from "./styles/GlobalStyles";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GlobalStyles>
        <h1>This is a test line</h1>
      </GlobalStyles>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**GlobalStyles.js**

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
html {
  font-size: 8px;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  font-weight: 200;
}
body {
  font-size: 8px;
  
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

`;

export default GlobalStyles;
```

***Console Error***[enter image description here][1]

```
GlobalStyle.js:28 The global style component sc-global-dtGiqY was given child JSX. createGlobalStyle does not render children.
```

***Error Screenshot***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJBLz.png

Comment: Is the error message not enough? It is saying that `GlobalStyle` doesn't render children. See https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place `<GlobalStyles />` as a sibling to your other content—not as a parent element trying to accept children.

```
<div className="App">
  <GlobalStyles />
  <h1>This is a test line</h1>   
</div>
```